# Retrieving user attributes(alias, required and custom) in amazon cognito userpool for android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

The document below shows that we need to use GetDetailsHandler to retrieve user attributes for android.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/tutorial-integrating-user-pools-android.html#tutorial-integrating-user-pools-user-details-android

I've tried that and in onSuccess(), I did

```
GetDetailsHandler getDetailsHandler = new GetDetailsHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(CognitoUserDetails cognitoUserDetails) {
        Map userAtts = cognitoUserDetails.getAttributes().getAttributes();
        String userName =       userAtts.get("alias:preferred_username").toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Exception exception) {
       }
    };
```

username is still returned null. I implemented it in onCreate(). Am I doing it wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initialize the map first after that you can use

```
Map userAtts=new HashMap();
userAtts =cognitoUserDetails.getAttributes().getAttributes();
String userName = userAtts.get("alias:preferred_username").toString();
```

it works

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to access the value in the standard user attribute "preferred_username", then the key is just "preferred_username". 
 To access the preferred username try this:

```
Map userAtts    = cognitoUserDetails.getAttributes().getAttributes();
String userName = userAtts.get("preferred_username").toString();
```